# Event for selecting an option even though value is not changed in dijit.form.Select.

Tags: drop-down-menu, dojo, onchange, dijit.form

I need help in figuring out the event that is fired when I select a dropdown value from `dijit.form.Select`. I already know of the `onChange` event and would like to know an event which fired even when the value is not changed.

**Use Case**

I am using dijit.form.Select in my project. I have some values like {Multiple,a,b,c,d} in this select drop down. When I select Multiple then it launches the pop up dialog. When I select other values a,b,c or d then that value gets set in that drop down.

Currently I catch onChange event to check if user has selected "Multiple" value so that I can launch the pop up dialog.

Now here is one issue. 1. Lets assume that by default selected value is a. 2. Now I select Multiple, onChange gets fired and pop up dialog gets launched. 3. Now again if I select Multiple then onChange event won't be fired and thus code would not launch pop up dialog.

I want to launch this dialog every time user selects "Multiple" value in the dropdown. Any suggestions to do this? I have tried useing onClick, onBlur and onFocus events but they are not of much use to me.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Capture the  `'onExecute'` event of the `dropDown` of the `dijit.form.Select` widget for this behaviour. However, keep in mind that you wont get the newVal as an argument to the function for this event. to get the new value, use the following line as the first line of your function:

```
var newVal = this.focusedChild.option.value;
```

This will work for sure :)